# using find() to find elements in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, find

I have a vector which stores some integers. In this vector, there can be all numbers except 10, 12, 31 cannot appear together or in pairs i.e., 10 and 12, 10 and 31, 12 and 31, 10 12 and 31 are invalid. I have come up with the following approach:

```
int main(){ 
int a[] = {10,2,31}; //can be of any size
vector<int> v(a, a+3);
short cnt = 0;
if(find(v.begin(), v.end(), 10) != v.end())
 ++cnt;
if(find(v.begin(), v.end(), 12) != v.end())
 ++cnt;
if(find(v.begin(), v.end(), 31) != v.end())
 ++cnt;

if(cnt > 1) 
  cout<<"Invalid options";
else 
  cout<<"Valid options";

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

which works. Is there a better way to do this? Especially, since the vector can contain any number of elements, can there be any downside?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `count`:

```
template <class InputIterator, class T>
  typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type
    count ( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, const T& value );
```

(see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count/)

or, `count_if` (which only traverses the list once):

```
template <class InputIterator, class Predicate>
  typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::difference_type
    count_if ( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Predicate pred );
```

which requires the minor extra work of a predicate, something like:

```
bool checkvalues(int i) {
    return (i==10 || i==12 || i==31);
}
```

or you could be more clever and make a class with `operator()` if you want to specify the possible values at runtime.

(see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count_if/)

Is the issue about invalid pairs and triples a red herring?

Comment: count_if can do this in 1 pass. so why others?

Answer (score 2):

If you sort them then you can use `std::binary_search`, which will run faster when the number of elements in the vector is large (would need to be very large though to have any noticeable difference).

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
if (std::binary_search(v.begin(), v.end(), 10)) cnt++;
if (std::binary_search(v.begin(), v.end(), 12)) cnt++;
if (std::binary_search(v.begin(), v.end(), 31)) cnt++;
```

Comment: Had thought about the same. If this piece of code is in a loop, and the contents of vector change at the beginning of each iteration,  then using your approach will be better, wont it?

Comment: No, because the sorting will take more time than the 3 finds. If v isn't sorted then find (or count_if) are your best options. You can't beat O(n) search on unsorted data.

Comment: Using sort and binary_search, or just using find, depends on how often the search will be done. If you only do a few finds for each time you insert/remove an element the find approach would likely be better. If you do a lot of searches per insert then the sort/search approach would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `set_intersection`, as in the example below:

```
int a[] = {10,2,12}; //can be of any size
int b[] = {10,12,31}; // set we are interested in, sorted already to save a sort

sort (a, a+3);

vector<int> dest(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])); // matching items will go here
vector<int>::iterator it;

it = set_intersection (a, a+3, b, b+3, dest.begin());

if (distance(dest.begin(), it) > 1) // oops means more than one item has matched...
```

Answer (score -1):

You should always use brackets around if statements even if the statement is only 1 line long.

```
if(find(v.begin(), v.end(), 31) != v.end())
 ++cnt;
```

Reading your code can get very confusing without the brackets. And if you want to add another statement to that if condition, you could introduce a very hard to debug error.